# Not getting polynomial regression curve, instead getting straight lines using numpy polyfit and poly1d functions

Tags: python

I'm running below code to run polynomial regression on independent variable (xhp) and dependent variable (yp). Problem is in the output I'm not getting smooth curved lines instead getting straight lines. Enclosed is the snippet of the output.

Also, with the predicted price on degree of freedom 3 here's how the data looks in a DataFrame which seems as the sorting is also in place.

[data_new DataFrame:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Axnpz.png)

### Python Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xhp = [88,76,101,86,102,115,262,58,176,60]
yp = [8921,7295,12945,8845,13950,17450,36000,6479,32250,5399]
polyreg = np.polyfit(xhp, yp, 3)
polypred = np.poly1d(polyreg)
predp = polypred(xhp)
data_new = pd.DataFrame({"Horsepower":xhp, "OrigPrice":yp,"PredPrice":predp})
plt.scatter(data_new["Horsepower"],data_new["OrigPrice"])
plt.plot(data_new["Horsepower"], data_new["PredPrice"], color = "red")
plt.xlabel("Horpower")
plt.ylabel("Original Price")
plt.title("Polynomial Curve on Predicted Price")
plt.show()
```

[Output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7yIp.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have 10 points.  That doesn't give you a smooth curve.  If you want a smooth curve, use more points:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xhp = [88,76,101,86,102,115,262,58,176,60]
yp = [8921,7295,12945,8845,13950,17450,36000,6479,32250,5399]
plt.scatter(xhp,yp)

polyreg = np.polyfit(xhp, yp, 3)
polypred = np.poly1d(polyreg)

x1 = np.arange(50,262,2)
predp = polypred(x1)
plt.plot(x1, predp, color = "red")

plt.xlabel("Horsepower")
plt.ylabel("Original Price")
plt.title("Polynomial Curve on Predicted Price")
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]